# Why doesn't this Class call work?

Tags: java

```
public static void Box()
{
    String[] statement =  new String [3];
    Censor c = new Censor();   
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(yes))
    {
        System.out.print(name+": >>");
        c.Replacement(statement[0]) = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name+":" + statement[0]);
        System.out.print(name+": >>");
        c.Replacement(statement[1]) = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name+":" + statement[1]);
        System.out.print(name+": >>");
        c.Replacement(statement[2]) = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name+":" + statement[2]);
        if(!statement[2].equals(empty))
        {
            System.out.print(name+": >>");
            c.Replacement(statement[0]) = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name+":" + statement[0]);
            System.out.print(name+": >>");
            c.Replacement(statement[1]) = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name+":" + statement[1]);
            System.out.print(name+": >>");
            c.Replacement(statement[2]) = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(name+":" + statement[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is an attempt to call the Censor class and use the method "Replacement" at each input so that it replaces the words specified in the Censor class with "****".

The compiling program I use says specifically that "Censor c = new Censor();" isn't possible because it can't find "symbol: class Censor". It might just be due to the program itself, but I just need to make sure incase it's a problem with how I wrote this.

Here's the Censor class in question.

```
public class Censor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
    public static void Censore(String[] statement)
    {
        String[] words = new String[3];
        Scanner blah = new Scanner(System.in);
        words[0] = statement[0];
        words[1] = statement[1];
        words[2] = statement[2];
        String replaceString = "";
        int loopcount = 0;
        while(loopcount < 1)
        {
            replaceString = words[0].replace("Blank", "****");
            replaceString = words[0].replace("Seer", "****");
            replaceString = words[0].replace("Nyah", "****");
            System.out.println(replaceString);
        }
    }
}
```

Editted just to get rid of the swear words

Comment: Did you import the class Censor?

Comment: I don't think I did... all you do is put "import Censor;" before the class name right?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the class if its in another package you need to import it using
     `Import packagename.classname` .Another thing you called

```
c.Replacement(statement[0])
```

and your method is

`Censore(String[] statement)`

Answer (score 0):

Statements like

```
c.Replacement(statement[0]) = input.nextLine();
```

are invalid.  You cannot have a method invocation on the left side of an assignment.  If you were trying to assign to `statement[0]` the result of applying your `Replacement` method to the result of `input.nextLine()`, the correct statement is

```
input.nextLine[0] = c.Replacement(input.nextLine());
```

Also, as @Omar points out, you don't actually have a method called `Replacement` in the `Censor` class.  You do have `Censore`, though, so you either need to rename `Censore` to `Replacement` or change all the references to `Replacement` to `Censore`.

Actually, because `Censore`/`Replacement` is a `static` method of class `Censor`, you don't need a `Censor` object in order to call it.  You can just write, for example

```
input.nextLine[0] = Censor.Replacement(input.nextLine());
```

Then you don't need `Censor c = new Censor();` at all.  You'll still need to sort out the possible issue of needing to import the `Censor` class, however...